# how to set password for wso2 dblookup mediator from property?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm working on outter database that could its password changed immediately.
so I'm trying to set password from a property.
or by registry at least (if it possible please attach any example or steps).

this is the mediator xml :

```
 <dblookup>
            <connection>
                <pool>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db</url>
                    <user>root</user>
                    <password>root</password>
                </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
                <sql><![CDATA[select * from students]]></sql>
                <result column="grade" name="grade"/>
            </statement>
        </dblookup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the DBlookup mediator configurations to the registry. Refer to the following sample configuration [1].

```
<dblookup xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<connection>
    <pool>
        <password key="conf:/repository/esb/password"/>
        <driver key="conf:/repository/esb/driver"/>
        <url key="conf:/repository/esb/url"/>
        <user key="conf:/repository/esb/username"/>
    </pool>
</connection>
</dblookup>
```

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/DBLookup+Mediator+#d5782bec440d44ae9de95dc569d308ea

Comment: I made local entry registry but it does not work, how should I make the registry ?

Comment: I read local Entry but now I need to read from env variable.
how could I do that ?

Comment: Injecting Environment variables are support only for few of the services.  It seems that the dblookup mediator is not supported [1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Injecting+Parameters+as+Environment+Variables#07f1482d551f4abb96c29d2ebc52e0c2